How to implement user authentication in Blazor Server with Entra External ID?
I am developing a Blazor Server application (.net 9) with Cosmos DB as database. I would like to add user auth with Entra External ID.
The only good docs I found are with Asp.Net MVC, here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/tutorial-web-app-dotnet-sign-in-prepare-app
Does anyone have a github example app with Blazor? Or a link to tutorial?

I managed to make it work with the following steps.
Entra External ID Steps

Create an external tenant:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/how-to-create-external-tenant-portal

Prepare your external tenant:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/tutorial-web-app-dotnet-sign-in-prepare-tenant


Blazor Application Steps

Add package Microsoft.Identity.Web: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Web

Configure your Blazor application in appsettings.json:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/external-id/customers/tutorial-web-app-dotnet-sign-in-prepare-app#configure-the-application-for-authentication

Add authentication and authorization to program.cs


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
...

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


Add authorization at the page level. Before the page is rendered, it will ask for the user be authenticated:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-9.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorize-attribute

Add authorization at the component level. The page is rendered, but some components are only displayed to authenticated users:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-9.0&tabs=visual-studio#authorizeview-component

Add authorization at the code level: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-9.0&tabs=visual-studio#procedural-logic



I don't have a complete answer for you, but I will tell you my experience.  I created a Blazor Server App in .net 6 and used Azure Active Directory.
To try it, use an older version of VS 22 that has .net 6 and create a new Blazor Server Project and select "Microsoft Identity".  It will create the project with AAD and it works great.
However, my experiance was that there was quite a learning curve on the AAD side (not the Blazor side, the Blazor side was quite straightforward, and mainly consisted of adding the correct settings for AAD).
I have not upgraded the Project to Entra, but as I understand it, it's just AAD renamed.
I don't know why, but I have not seen the same option for "Microsoft Identity" in the later version of .net after 6.  I am guessing that the same code would work, it's just not supported by the Wizard any more.
Like I said, this is not a complete answer, but hope it points you in the right direction.

Check out these Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/blazor-web-app-with-entra?view=aspnetcore-9.0
